# axios send image through post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, electron, axios

I'm trying to send an image through `axios` POST request. The request is going through, but the image is not uploading.

Here is my code,

```
const screenshotPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'screenshot.png');

var bodyFormData = new FormData();
//bodyFormData.append('uploadedFile', screenshotPath);
bodyFormData.append('uploadedFile', fs.createReadStream(screenshotPath));

axios({
 method: 'post',
 url: url,
 data: bodyFormData,
 config: {
  headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
  }
 }
})
```

Is it because of the filename path ?

this is my `screenshotPath`

> C:\Users\oem\AppData\Local\Temp\screenshot.png

Comment: have you tried `fs.readFile`

Comment: Can you give me an example please.

Comment: Here it is `fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function(err, data) {  
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
});`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `createReadStream` function from the File System library of `Node`. But Node is running on server-side and here you are working with a react application which is running on client side.

Please check [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications) on how to upload files from front-end applications.

Comment: I also tried bodyFormData.append('uploadedFile', screenshotPath); instead of the createReadStream with no hope. Please note, I'm using electron.js

Comment: Ok, didn't know that you were using electron. You should add this information in your post.